Get a "higher up" value if the first value doesn't meet criteria
I am working on a query to pull in employee information, including who can approve the employee's timecards. Our database includes who the employee reports to, but that person won't necessarily be the one who can approve timecards. The data looks like this



EENum
Position
Reports to




1
Laborer
3


2
Laborer
3


3
Foreman
6


4
Laborer
5


5
Foreman
7


6
Super
8


7
Super
8


8
PM
8



In this example, only the "Super" and "PM" positions can approve timecards. Since employees 1 and 2 report to employee 3, who is a foreman and can't approve timecards, I need a query that will look into employee 3's data to see who they report to, in this case employee 6 who is a Super and can therefore approve their timecards. So the final output of the query would need to look like this:



EENum
Approved By




1
6


2
6


3
6


4
7


5
7


6
8


7
8


8
8



And while not common, there are instances where there could be a 3rd "layer", so I can't just do an "IF" statement to go up a single level. It needs to go up until it finds a "reports to" whose position allows them to approve timecards.
I've tried doing recursive searches, but they haven't pulled the information in correctly, and unfortunately I don't understand recursive searches well enough to explain what's going on with the returned data.
I also would prefer to not use temporary tables, as multiple people will need to use this query and some of them don't have the access level to create and delete temporary tables.

A user reporting to themselves rather than NULL was a deliberate choice in our dataset for reasons I won't go into. It gets applied even more rarely than the example dataset may imply, but since it DOES happen I included one as an example to ensure that it was accounted for in the answers.

This should walk the tree until you find a suitable approver:
with tree as (
    select EENum as EEBase, EENum, ReportsTo, 'N' as approver
    from Employees
    union all
    select EEBase, e.EENum, e.ReportsTo,
        case when e.Position in ('PM', 'Super') then 'Y' else 'N' end
    from tree t inner join Employees e on e.EENum = t.ReportsTo
    where t.approver = 'N'
)
select EEBase as EENum, EENum as ApprovedBy
from tree
where approver = 'Y';

https://dbfiddle.uk/0nrOydrD
The data has an approver who reports to himself/herself. That's able to terminate on the first pass. If you have such a cycle on a non-approving position then it would cause an error. I don't understand the intention of  this (usually the top level would be set to null) and I don't know if the query needs to handle either of these scenarios differently.

When I try this, I get a max recursion error no matter how high I set the option

@JoelCoehoorn I may have fixed it by correcting one of the aliases just a few minutes before your comment.

Still fails for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/SCUX3W3Q

Also: the idea from the question is one laborer may have more than one approver in their tree, and he wants to stop at the first approver.

@JoelCoehoorn Looks like employee 8 reports to him/herself. Yes, I'm aware of stopping as soon as one is found.

Still fails if I change the data so 8 reports to NULL https://dbfiddle.uk/iNyaIFUO

@shawnt00 thank you so much! I was able to get this to work in the actual database and based on my testing it has worked. I plan to go through your solution more in depth so I can get a better understanding of recursion in general. I can't upvote your answer right now since I don't have enough reputation, so I'll have to try and get some more.

@JoelCoehoorn Thanks for running troubleshooting. I had initially thought the max recursion was done because of the edits I had to make when running in the full dataset.

@DaleK Thank you!

You can use following Recursive CTE query to get the expected results. I've even included 1 more level in my test data & it works very well.
WITH ApproverCTE AS (
    -- Anchor member: Start with all employees
    SELECT 
        E.EENum AS EmployeeID,
        E.Position,
        E.ReportsTo,
        E.EENum AS RootEmployeeID -- Keep track of the original employee
    FROM 
        Employees E

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive member: Move up the hierarchy until we find a "Super" or "PM"
    SELECT 
        E.EENum AS EmployeeID,
        E.Position,
        E.ReportsTo,
        CTE.RootEmployeeID
    FROM 
        Employees E
    INNER JOIN 
        ApproverCTE CTE ON E.EENum = CTE.ReportsTo
    WHERE 
        E.Position NOT IN ('Super', 'PM') -- Continue recursion if the position isn't a Super or PM
)
-- Final selection: Find the approver for each employee
SELECT 
    CTE.RootEmployeeID AS EmployeeID,
    E.EENum AS ApprovedBy
FROM 
    ApproverCTE CTE
INNER JOIN 
    Employees E ON CTE.ReportsTo = E.EENum
WHERE 
    E.Position IN ('Super', 'PM') -- Select only approvers who are Super or PM
ORDER BY 
    EmployeeID;

Please checkout dbFiddle here.

Hi @GrantBaugh, let me know if this query works for you or not.
